# How to combine columns in R when columns don't match?

Tags: r, data-binding, merge, multiple-columns, cbind

**I am mainly raising this issue to ask for opinions on how you would approach this problem. I have created a roundabout solution myself but I'm interested in solutions that might be simple/more straight forward/easier to replicate in a model, etc. Looking forward to reading your solutions.**

I've looked for a while and I couldn't find the solution I was looking for so I apologise if someone has provided the answer already but I haven't come across it.

The problem I faced was combining the columns of two dataframes in R but without any matching names or rows. I came up with the solution below:

## Splitting Communication "Medium" and "Description" from Communication Description

```
library(stringr)
split <- str_split_fixed(market$Communication.Description, '[[:punct:]]', 2)
```

`split <- data.frame(split)` # Trnasform split from array to dataframe
`names(split) <- c("medium", "description")` # Give meaningful names to the columns

## Merge "market" and "split"

```
market$medium <- split$medium
market$description <- split$description
```

Basically I ended up assigning the columns in the split dataframe I created into two new columns in the market dataframe.

I talked to a couple of colleagues afterwards and they said that I could have used "cbind" which I haven't used before.

Comment: I have made it work for me but I would like to get an idea for the community consensus on approaching this problem. If you need me to explain anything further please ask.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create two new columns in the dataframe I was targeting and assigned the two columns from the second dataframe into those two new columns as shown above

```
library(stringr)

split <- str_split_fixed(market$Communication.Description, '[[:punct:]]', 2)
```

`split <- data.frame(split)` # Trnasform split from array to dataframe names(split) <- `c("medium", "description")` # Give meaningful names to the columns

Merge "market" and "split"

```
market$medium <- split$medium
market$description <- split$description
```